# Why am I getting "inferred type is Observable<T?>! but Observable<T> was expected" with Observable Kotlin extension function?

Tags: kotlin, extension-function

I have the following extension function:

```
import io.reactivex.Notification
import io.reactivex.Observable
import io.reactivex.subjects.Subject

fun <T> Subject<Notification<T>>.fromNotifications(): Observable<T> {
    return compose {
        it.takeUntil { event ->
            !event.isOnNext
        }.flatMap { event ->
            when {
                event.isOnError -> Observable.error(event.error)
                event.isOnNext -> Observable.just(event.value)
                else -> Observable.empty()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use it to convert a `Subject` with `Notification` values to ordinary `Observable`.

I don't quite understand why I'm getting the error

`Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is Observable<T?>! but Observable<T> was expected`

Where does `inferred type is Observable<T?>` come from? I guess it's related to the fact that in Java there's no difference between nullable and non-nullable types.

What are the ways to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's happening because `event.value` is marked as `@Nullable`, so `Observable.just(event.value)` is an `Observable<T?>`.  You can make this compile by changing the return type to be `Observable<T?>`, or by using the `!!` operator to assert that `event.value` is not null when creating the Observable (or by otherwise dealing with a null value explicitly):

```
fun <T> Subject<Notification<T>>.fromNotifications(): Observable<T> {
    return compose {
        it.takeUntil { event ->
            !event.isOnNext
        }.flatMap { event ->
            when {
                event.isOnError -> Observable.error(event.error)
                event.isOnNext -> Observable.just(event.value!!)
                else -> Observable.empty()
            }
        }
    }
}
```